# Typecast Obligation is Apple Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Am I missing something or typecast is obligatory while adding numbers having different types:

```
var i:Int=5
var d:Double=6.0

var q:Double= i + d // this is error?!
var w:Double= Double(i) + d // this is ok
```

Comment: As the book says: "Conversions between integer and floating-point numeric types must be made explicit:"

Comment: But it makes my code so messy! Any trick or escape route?

Comment: It makes your code 'so predictable' as well.

Comment: Any shortcut keyword that replaces Double(d)?

Comment: I think it makes the intent of you code explicit. If you desperately wanted to you could: `func + (left: Int, right: Double) -> Double {
    return Double(left) + right
}`

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something or typecast is obligatory while adding numbers having different types:

No you are not missing something, typecasting is obligatory.

I think it's fine for arithmetic operations because it makes you think about your type conversions, however, the same rule applies to bit shifting. i.e.

```
var i: UInt64 = 6
var j: Int = 3
var k = i << j // error
```

This is really annoying and wrong.  I've raised a bug with Apple, but they haven't done anything about it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't provide automatic conversion between numeric types.

Normally you just perform conversions like you used in your question.

I don't recommend it, but you could do this:

```
func +(i:Int, d:Double) -> Double {
    return Double(i) + d
}

let i: Int = 1
let d: Double = 7.0
i + d
// result: 8.0
```

You would need to provide a lot of overrides to cover all the bases.  Like I said, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Note `1 + 7.0` would work anyway. "The rules for combining numeric constants and variables are different from the rules for numeric literals. The literal value 3 can be added directly to the literal value 0.14159, because number literals do not have an explicit type in and of themselves. Their type is inferred only at the point that they are evaluated by the compiler."

Answer (score -1):

I know it's unsafe but for some big math routines it's ok, using @Mike Pollard method to override default + & - operators :

```
func + (left: Int, right: Double) -> Double { return Double(left) + right }
func + (left: Double, right: Int) -> Double { return left + Double(right) }
func - (left: Int, right: Double) -> Double { return Double(left) - right }
func - (left: Double, right: Int) -> Double { return left - Double(right) }
```

Comment: Yes, that's extremely unsafe as your overloads for `-` do addition. :)

Comment: Let's all just agree never to do this :)